# Exporting android app with connections to MySQL database

Tags: android, mysql, database

I'm new to the whole android app process and I'm trying to get my head around a few things. I am creating a recipe app in which recipes will be retrieved from a MySQL database. Users can search with a keyword and matching recipes are fetched and displayed in a ListView.

I will be using PHP, JSON, XML, etc... for the Webservices (as suggested by many people) and the database will be stored on my PC during development. I'd

The thing I'm trying to understand is that as it's a MySQL database running on my computer, would connections to the database only be accessible from my PC? Meaning that if I wanted to develop at university, I'd have to physically bring my PC with me?

So eventually when I export the app as an apk and send it to a few of my friends and family members for them to use, would the app still be able to communicate to the database located on my computer or would my database somehow have to be stored within the app itself?

How would the end user using the app be able to communicate to my PC's database if it's using a localhost connection? That's what I am trying to understand.

If there's any information out there that is useful that will help me understand, please share it with me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ideal solution would be sign up on one of the free web hosting sites that provide you a Domain name, MySQL and PHP capabilities (they are plenty of them out there).

http://www.000webhost.com/

http://byet.host

and the list goes on..

So all your development can be deployed on these free hosting sites and then from your android app you can connect to the PHP web service. In this way you would not need to expose your PC's MYSQL database server on the internet to be accessible by everyone.

Comment: do you have any documentation on how to set up such a solution? like what program would I use for the PHP web service?

Comment: Look at nusoap library for php. Very easy to setup. You will find lots of guides on setting up. http://www.ahowto.net/php/creating-webservice-server-and-client-using-nusoap/ for nusoap server and in your android app you can use any client ( plenty available )

Comment: thanks for the link. so if I understood you correctly... I buy/sign up for a web domain. I find one which allows me to get MySQL, PHP and phpMyAdmin on this domain. Then I simply set up the DB and PHP part on the domain and use my home PC to develop the app. Then simply connect the two together?

Comment: These free hosting providers provide free domain names also. 1st steps - Sign up, 2nd step - configuring webservice on your site, 3rd step - Deploy your php application with nusoap on the site, 4th step connect android application  to webservice. Step 3 might be repeated many time as go by building your application. So all in all development would happen on your pc but then you deploy on your site for testing.